# Recursively call JsonSerializer in a JsonConverter

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

I'm writing a `JsonConverter` to perform some conversion tasks I need accomplished on read/write. In particular, I'm taking the existing serialization behavior and tacking on some additional properties on write / reading those additional properties on read.

Inside the `JsonConverter`, I'd like to make use of the passed `JsonSerializer` instance to perform the majority of the conversion functionality. However, when I do this, I end up in a recursive loop where the serializer calls into my converter which calls into the serializer which calls into the converter and etc.

I've seen people do things such as use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject`, passing in all the converters from the serializer instance *except* `this`. However, that won't work for me because it bypasses all of the other customization I've done on my serializer, such as custom contract resolver and `DateTime` handling.

Is there a way I can either:

1. Use the serializer instance passed to me, but somehow exclude my converter, or
2. Clone the serializer passed to me (without manually constructing a new one and copying it property by property) and remove my converter?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a very common problem. Using "JsonConvert.SerializeObject" isn't a bad idea. However, one trick that can be used in some circumstances (typically collections) is to cast to the interface when writing and deserialize to a simple derivative when reading.

Below is a simple converter that deals with dictionaries that might have been serialized as a set of KVPs rather than looking like an object (showing my age here :) )

Note "WriteJson" casts to IDictionary< K,V> and "ReadJson" uses "DummyDictionary". You end up with the right thing but uses the passed serializer without causing recursion.

```
/// <summary>
/// Converts a <see cref="KeyValuePair{TKey,TValue}"/> to and from JSON.
/// </summary>
public class DictionaryAsKVPConverter<TKey, TValue> : JsonConverter
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether this instance can convert the specified object type.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="objectType">Type of the object.</param>
    /// <returns>
    ///     <c>true</c> if this instance can convert the specified object type; otherwise, <c>false</c>.
    /// </returns>
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        if (!objectType.IsValueType && objectType.IsGenericType)
            return (objectType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(Dictionary<,>));

        return false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Writes the JSON representation of the object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="writer">The <see cref="JsonWriter"/> to write to.</param>
    /// <param name="value">The value.</param>
    /// <param name="serializer">The calling serializer.</param>
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var dictionary = value as IDictionary<TKey, TValue>;
        serializer.Serialize(writer, dictionary);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Reads the JSON representation of the object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="reader">The <see cref="JsonReader"/> to read from.</param>
    /// <param name="objectType">Type of the object.</param>
    /// <param name="existingValue">The existing value of object being read.</param>
    /// <param name="serializer">The calling serializer.</param>
    /// <returns>The object value.</returns>
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary;

        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
        {
            dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
            reader.Read();
            while (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
            {
                var kvp = serializer.Deserialize<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>(reader);
                dictionary[kvp.Key] = kvp.Value;
                reader.Read();
            }
        }
        else if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
            // Use DummyDictionary to fool JsonSerializer into not using this converter recursively
            dictionary = serializer.Deserialize<DummyDictionary>(reader);
        else
            dictionary = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();

        return dictionary;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Dummy to fool JsonSerializer into not using this converter recursively
    /// </summary>
    private class DummyDictionary : Dictionary<TKey, TValue> { }
}
```

Comment: Follow-up: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60254867/156755 if you'd care to take a look

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you don't explicitly check for `DummyDictionary` in `CanConvert`?

Comment: note that DummyDictionary is `private`. It can never be passed in. The instance of Dummy is cast/returned as a Dictionary which is what CanConvert checks for.
So, I think it's ok? What situation are you looking at?

Comment: Not a specific situation; it just seems a little clearer to me to write `if (objectType == typeof(DummyDictionary)) {return false;}`, and then perform the rest of the checks. This would allow adding a little more flexibility: e.g. any types implementing `IDIctionary<TKey, TValue>`, or including other types that inherit from `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`.

Comment: I don't think you'd want that. You'd still want to be able to serialize the result of a previous deserialize. Your change would prevent that.
Changing to IDictionary would be sensible. Though custom impls are pretty rare.
The code was just cut&paste from a project at the time. Worked for us :)

Answer (score 2):

**It is possible to disable your own converter for exactly one invocation of `Serialize`.** This will even work if the converter is used reentrantly and/or multi-threaded.

```cs
class MyConverter : JsonConverter
{
  [ThreadStatic]
  private static bool Disabled;

  public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) =>
    Disabled ? (Disabled = false) : the_type_condition;

  public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
  { ...
    try
    { Disabled = true;
      serializer.Serialize(writer, value); // will not invoke WriteJson recursively
    } finally
    { Disabled = false;
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

You can indeed use the serializer instance passed to your converter, and exclude the current converter. This will not be thread safe, however (see comments of this answer)

```
public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    serializer.Converters.Remove(this);
    serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
    serializer.Converters.Add(this);
}
```

Comment: This isn't thread-safe. Since almost all web-scale work is multithreaded, this doesn't actually help.

Comment: @DavidPfeffer it seems that would indeed be something to take into account. I think making a new serializer each time you need to serialize or deserialize something would solve this, but perhaps the impact on performance is too great to make that solution viable...

Answer (score -9):

Sorry, but maybe I'm confusing. I used this methods for serialize my objects:

```html
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Utilities
{
    public static class serializer
    {
        public static string SerializeObject(object objectModel) {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectModel);
        }
        public static object DeserializeObject<T>(string jsonObject)
        {
            try
            {
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(jsonObject);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { return null; }
            
        }
    }
}
```

and I used of this code:

```html
userLoged = (modelUser)serializer.DeserializeObject<modelUser>((string)Session["userLoged"]);
```

I hope this has been helpful.

Comment: This does not answer the question that was asked.  The question was not "How do I serialize my object using `JsonConvert`?"  It was asking how to avoid a recursive loop from inside a custom `JsonConverter`.  Note that [`JsonConvert`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert.htm) and [`JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter.htm) are two entirely different classes in Json.Net.